# Laravel querybuilder with raw SQL statement returns syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this SQL raw query that perfectly executes in mysql but i want to convert it to laravel querybuilder. When i do `toSql();` it returns me the exact raw query. But when i `get();` it returns me an syntax error.

My raw query which perfectly executes in sql and in laravel blade

```
            $items = \DB::select('
            SELECT users.name, users.email, users.phone, users.parent_id, users.section_id, finances.amount, finances.description, schoolyears.name, finances.date 
            from users 
            JOIN finances on users.id = finances.user_id 
            JOIN schoolyears on users.school_id = schoolyears.school_id 
            where finances.date=
            (select max(date) from finances f where finances.user_id=f.user_id)
            ');
```

Converted raw sql query to querybuilder that returns an syntax error

```
 $items = \DB::table('users')
                    ->join('finances', 'users.id','=','finances.user_id')
                    ->join('schoolyears', 'users.school_id','=','schoolyears.school_id')
                    ->select('users.name as uname','users.email','users.phone','users.section_id','finances.amount','finances.description','schoolyears.name','finances.date')
                    ->where('finances.date', '=' ,(\DB::raw("select max(`date`) from finances f where finances.user_id=f.user_id")))
                    ->get();
```

Error code

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'select max(`date`) from finances f 
where finances.user_id=f.user_id' at line 1 (SQL: select `users`.`name` as 
`uname`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`phone`, `users`.`section_id`, 
`finances`.`amount`, `finances`.`description`, `schoolyears`.`name`, 
`finances`.`date` from `users` inner join `finances` on `users`.`id` = 
`finances`.`user_id` inner join `schoolyears` on `users`.`school_id` = 
`schoolyears`.`school_id` where `finances`.`date` = select max(`date`) from 
finances f where finances.user_id=f.user_id)
```

Comment: share the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :  brackets were missing in raw query, so it is giving error.

```
->where('finances.date', '=' ,(\DB::raw("(select max(`date`) from finances f where finances.user_id=f.user_id)")))
```

Ex.

```
$items = \DB::table('users')
                    ->join('finances', 'users.id','=','finances.user_id')
                    ->join('schoolyears', 'users.school_id','=','schoolyears.school_id')
                    ->select('users.name as uname','users.email','users.phone','users.section_id','finances.amount','finances.description','schoolyears.name','finances.date')
                    ->where('finances.date', '=' ,(\DB::raw("(select max(`date`) from finances f where finances.user_id=f.user_id)")))
```

Comment: This works for me sir. Can you explain your answer to me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 $items = \DB::table('users')
                    ->join('finances', 'users.id','=','finances.user_id')
                    ->join('schoolyears', 'users.school_id','=','schoolyears.school_id')
                    ->select('users.name as uname','users.email','users.phone','users.section_id','finances.amount','finances.description','schoolyears.name','finances.date')
                    ->where('finances.date', '=' ,"(" . (\DB::raw("select max(`date`) from finances f where finances.user_id=f.user_id")) . ")")
                    ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: returns an empty collection sir
`
Collection {#552 ▼
  #items: []
}
`

Comment: And what it is supposed to return?

Comment: the fields that i selected sir.

Comment: its the same sir. it returns the same empty array. Ive got the answer already from @yasin patil. Thanks for your answers sir